# How To add shipping rates for weight based shipping in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Actually I want to add shipping rates based on region,I added shipping rates like below,

800:40.00,1250:60.00,1700:80.00,2200:100.00,2700:120.00,99999:40.00

If weight is 800 gms it should take 40 and also it should take from 800-1250gms 40 rs but even 1000gms it is taking 60 rs but it shouldn't take how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check in range:

```
function in_range($number, $min, $max)
{
    if (is_int($number) && is_int($min) && is_int($max))
    {
        return ($number >= $min && $number < $max);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Also you have create array like this:

```
$array = array(
  [0] => array(
    minw : 1,
    maxw : 1249,
    rate : 40
  ),
  [1] => array(
    minw : 1250,
    maxw : 1699,
    rate : 60
  )
);
```

After that to get rate use this loop function:

```
$weight = 500;

function get shipping_rate($array, $weight) {

    foreach($array as offset => $arr) {
        $minw = $arr['minw'];
        $maxw = $arr['maxw'];
        $rate = $arr['rate'];

        if(in_range($weight, $minw, $maxw)) {
            return $rate;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How to configure in backend

Comment: get all weight with shipping rate from database and form a sorted array according to weight and write a plugin which include that code.

Comment: Without that function I cant configure?

Comment: Try to use this extension if you know opencart: [Click here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-opencart-part-one--cms-25076)